# На запрос числа записанного в классе выдается ошибка

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

Код не работает. Я думал из-за того что я запрашиваю класс на той странице где его нет. Проверка присутствия класса тоже не помогла.

```js
doc2 = Jsoup.connect(NewLine).timeout(18*1000).get();
Elements elements = doc2.select("span.price");
if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
 Element priceElement = elements.get(0);
 System.out.println("есть цена");
    doc2 = Jsoup.connect(NewLine).get();
 priceElement = doc2.select("span.price").get(0);
    Здесь ошибка---> float price = Float.parseFloat(priceElement.text().substring(0, priceElement.text().lastIndexOf(" ")).replaceAll(" ", ""));
 System.out.println("цена="+price);
}else{
 System.out.println("Отсутствует цена");
}
```

Вылазит ошибка как и раньше

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

NewLine можно принят за "https://www.layta.ru/ip-kamery/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверить наличие элемента `<span class="price">` на странице `Document page` можно, например, так:

```
boolean contains = !page.select("span.price").isEmpty();
```

Так как для Вашего приложения отсутствие данного элемента на странице – ситуация скорее исключительная, то целесообразнее будет обработать исключение, чем делать проверку:

```
try {

    Element priceElement = page.select("span.price").get(0);
    ...
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    // обработка исключения
}
```

Однако, чисто технически, можно поступить и так:

```
Elements elements = page.select("span.price");

if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
    Element priceElement = elements.get(0);
    ...

} else {
    ...

}
```